# Local HTML website connecting to SQL Server

Tags: html, sql, dbconnection

I have created a theatre website with the help of html. I am trying to implement online ticketing locally within my system. I have created required columns in a SQL Server table.

How to link that? Eg. if I am submitting the ticket filling form in local html page, it should reflect in the database table where I created the columns. Please help

Comment: you should use a server to receive the data from the browser client. You can use PHP, Python

Comment: What language are you using to process the web-page submissions?

Comment: HTML alone for webpage